# How would I find the total area? On which steps?

Tags: area

How to find the total area between $f(x) = x^2 - x$ and the $x-$axis over $[-1,2]$?

Comment: Have you drawn a graph?

Answer (score 1):

You have the upper bound $x=2$ and lower bound $x=-1$
simply integrate
$$\int_{-1}^2y.dx$$
$$\int_{-1}^2x^2-x.dx$$
$$\int_{-1}^1x-x^2.dx+\int_1^2x^2-x.dx$$ should give you the answer

Answer (score 1):

$$
 y(x) = x^{2} - x
$$

[image: parabola]

---

Simplest interpretation:

$$
\int \left( x^{2} - x \right) dx =
\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^2}{2}
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_{-1}^{2} \left( x^{2} - x \right) dx =
%
\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{2}x^2 \Bigg\lvert_{-1}^{2} = 
\left( \frac{8}{3} - \frac{4}{2} \right) - 
\left( \frac{-1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} \right)
=
\frac{3}{2}
$$

---

The Wainfleet Conjecture:

@DanielWainfleet makes an interesting point. Does the OP want this integral?

[image: wainfleet]

Solve for the roots:
$$
 x^{2}-x = x(1-x) = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x=0, \ x = 1
$$
Parse the integral
$$
 \int_{-1}^0 f(x) \, dx - \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx + \int_{1}^{2} f(x) \, dx = \frac{5}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6} = \frac{11}{6}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The OP wants the area bounded by $y(x) = x^2 - x$ **and** the $x$-axis. Therefore, does the OP mean

$$\int_{-1}^0 (x^2-x) dx+\int_1^2 (x^2-x) dx=\frac{5}{3}?$$

Comment: The OP seems to be asking for $\int_{-1}^2|f(x)|dx$ although I could be wrong.

Comment: Even so, part of the integral is negative in the other solutions.